# Aggregate events with drf

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "event_datetime": "2020-03-12T22:39:55.273267Z",
        "event_type": "Production",
        "quantity": 58
    },
    {
        "event_datetime": "2020-03-12T22:49:55.273267Z",
        "event_type": "Production",
        "quantity": 108
    },
    {
        "event_datetime": "2020-03-12T23:39:55.273267Z",
        "event_type": "Waste",
        "quantity": 8
    },
    {
        "event_datetime": "2020-03-12T23:59:55.273267Z",
        "event_type": "Production",
        "quantity": 15
    }

]
```

What i wanna do is once i have an event followed by another that has the same type i'd like to output on another endpoint the following structure:

```
[
    {

        "start_datetime": "2020-03-12T22:39:55.273267Z",
        "end_datetime": "2020-03-12T22:49:55.273267Z",
        "event_type": "Production",
        "quantity": 108
    },
    {
        "start_datetime": "2020-03-12T23:39:55.273267Z",
        "end_datetime": "2020-03-12T23:39:55.273267Z"
        "event_type": "Waste",
        "quantity": 8
    },
    {
        "start_datetime": "2020-03-12T23:59:55.273267Z",
        "end_datetime": "2020-03-12T23:59:55.273267Z"
        "event_type": "Production",
        "quantity": 15
    }

]
```

I also want to do that without having to save this structure on db. How could i do this using DRF?

Answer (score 0):

The below code should serve your needs.

```
import json
events = [
    {
        "event_datetime": "2020-03-12T22:39:55.273267Z",
        "event_type": "Production",
        "quantity": 58
    },
    {
        "event_datetime": "2020-03-12T22:49:55.273267Z",
        "event_type": "Production",
        "quantity": 108
    },
    {
        "event_datetime": "2020-03-12T22:52:55.273267Z",
        "event_type": "Production",
        "quantity": 100
    },
    {
        "event_datetime": "2020-03-12T23:39:55.273267Z",
        "event_type": "Waste",
        "quantity": 8
    },
    {
        "event_datetime": "2020-03-12T23:59:55.273267Z",
        "event_type": "Production",
        "quantity": 15
    }

]
temp_event = events.pop(0)
prev_event_type = temp_event['event_type']
prev_datetime = temp_event.pop('event_datetime')
temp_event['start_datetime'] = prev_datetime
amended_events = [temp_event]

for event in events:
  temp_event = event
  end_datetime = event.pop('event_datetime')
  event['start_datetime'] = end_datetime
  event['end_datetime'] = end_datetime
  if prev_event_type == event['event_type']:
    prev_event = amended_events.pop()
    prev_starttime = prev_event['start_datetime']
    event['start_datetime'] = prev_starttime
  prev_event_type = temp_event['event_type']
  prev_datetime = end_datetime
  amended_events.append(event)

print(json.dumps(amended_events, indent=4))
```

For DRF, create a new function and pass the events as a parameter and return the amended_events.

Let me know if this is something you wanted.

Comment: Hi @Tarun Dev, thanks a lot for your help i tried to do what you said and had the following error ```TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer```, here is the code i tried to do. ```def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.Meta.fields = list(self.Meta.fields)
        self.Meta.fields.pop('event_datetime')
        self.Meta.fields.pop('created')
        self.Meta.fields.pop('modified')
        self.Meta.fields.append('start_datetime')
        self.Meta.fields.append('end_datetime')
        super(AvailabilitySerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)```

Comment: Probably my comment might be too late. The pop() function accepts the index which should be integer, you're passing string.